# My object wont rotate 360 degrees instead id only does a fast 180

Tags: animation, transforms, keyframes

I only startet using blender so i am an amateur and probably messed up quite a lot in my project so be kind.

When I want to animate my objects (a head in this case) to rotate 360 degrees the "transform" options wont seem to work correctly. Keyframe 1 is set my Z-Rotation to 0 and at keyframe 90 I set it to 360. But the head will only rotate 180 very quick (12ish frames) and wont rotate anymore for the rest of the duration.

I know its kind of a bad description but i can upload my project somewhere so you guys better understand what I mean.

I cant seem to figure this out because from all the tutorials I watched my approach should work. So i messed something up and now I cant figure out what :D

Here is the link to a Imgur Video of my problem https://imgur.com/a/iMAqmF8

Comment: A quick look at your video confirms my suspicion, I believe the culprit is the fact that your rotations are set to quaternion which can sometimes become quite tricky to work with. On the side bar where you see the rotation values highlighted in yellow, you could try clicking "quaternion" below that and changing it to XYZ. Make sure to delete your keyframes and create them again and it should work.

Comment: True .. Quaternion interpolation will always take the great circle route across the sphere of orientations.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.